# Is it a security/privacy risk to sell a used printer?

Tags: security, printing, printer, storage, privacy

I am about to trash or sell off my old printer, [Xerox Phaser 3122](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/product/phaser-3122/), and I wonder if this poses any security/privacy risk?

How do I check if any of my past printing jobs are stored inside this printer? Have you heard of such a feature in a printer, outside of James Bond movie?

This probably wouldn't make a lot of economical sense, but I wanted your opinion.

Comment: Print the front pages of 20 newspapers from the web; then all that could be cached would be today's news. Any more than 20 is I think, into 007 territory, but idk the model so don't know how big [or even volatile] its cache could be. Xerox doesn't seem to have any info on that page, it seems to be 15 years old or more.

Comment: You could also just Hulk smash the PCB

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/228895/security-considerations-when-selling-a-printer and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178190/if-i-sell-my-printer-can-the-last-printed-pages-be-recovered-and-how-can-i-wip

Comment: This printer has 8mb of RAM only with no long term storage options.  When you unplug the printer, all of whatever it *might* have contained is gone.  You should be safe the moment you unplug it.

Comment: Unless the printer has NVRAM storage or a hard disk — the professional printers do — then there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 8):

There are only 2 places a printer can store sensitive data: in non-volatile memory (NVRAM), or on a hard disk. Normal memory is volatile, and loses all data when you switch the printer off.

A hard disk is the only place where a printer can permanently store documents. NVRAM is used to store things like printer settings and network settings. Of these, only network settings (IP address, WiFi password, etc) could present a problem.

I have not found any kind of manual or data sheet for your printer online. The Xerox support page you linked is similarly useless: regardless of what I typed into it, the result was always "no results". Hence what follows is a "best guess".

I'm pretty certain your printer does not have a hard disk - only top-end printers have those. Hence, your printer cannot store any documents.

That leaves NVRAM. Xerox no longer seem to have any manuals or data sheets available for the Phaser 3122, but I found specs [here](http://specsan.com/printers-and-mfps-xerox/xerox-phaser-3122/), which state that the only interfaces on your printer are USB and parallel. Neither of those require any sensitive settings.

In all, I am confident that your printer does not store anything that you might consider private. I do however wonder who would want to buy an ancient printer like this, with no support, and most likely only a USB-1.0 (i.e. slow) interface.

EDIT

I should add, if the printer is working well, why get rid of it? It's reasonably fast, as well as cheap to run: third party toners cost about 0.1c per page. If you're thinking of getting a colour printer, keep this one for mono.

Answer (score 1):

Those that are saying that ***once you unplug the electricity*** the cache ram is erased and your worries are over, ***are only half right***. In another life, I was responsible for computer security for a Fed gov facility.

It has been shown numerous times by security experts that computer video and volatile ram can be read up to about 3-4hrs with 1/2hr being the norm. Laptops have been shown to be particularly vulnerable. So unless someone grabs your printer a few minutes after your use, removes or jumpers the chips - your ok.

If I were a drug dealer printing labels, accountant for a "massage" parlor with a client list, or printing receipts for arms sales to Russia, I would let the printer set for 24hrs before putting it in the trash (which the FBI can legally take).

It depends on actual RAM modules (generation, capacity etc) and temperature.

- The higher the capacity (more MB/GB), the smaller the capacitors are,
  the quicker they discharge.
- The lower the voltage supply, the less charge is stored and it dissipates quicker.
- The higher the temperature, the quicker the charge dissipates.

On an interesting point of interest, about 15 years ago the Federal Gov was caught reading prisoner legal info from typewriters with cache memory - after prisoners left the legal room, the Gov would quickly go in and print the cache out and give it to prosecutors. It was eventually discovered they had deliberately purchased typewriters with large cache memory to take advantage of this exploit. I assume one of the security agencies tipped them off on how to do this. ***"Where there is a will, there is a way!"*** :-(

Comment: A very nice post.  I am glad you wrote it.  I knew my comment wouldn't be 100% accurate until time had passed but for 90% of us.. especially people selling printers on craigslist.. it should be fine.  I don't know how relevant it will be for the OP but I am still glad you wrote this. +1

Comment: I think you and others are right in principle and realistically. I was splitting hairs and hopefully adding a little knowledge for any younger or inexperienced. We now live in a world where tech, marketing, governments, and other parties are harming us. The deceit is never ending - I just learned advertisers emit sub-audible tones/code through the TV that your cell phone picks up and they can tell what program or add you watched. Your TV does not have to be connected to the Internet. If someone had told me this 5 years ago I would have thought they were crazy and needed a tin foil hat!